# Set postion of gridview column with autogenerated column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `Gridview` with autogenerated `Column = "true"` Now I want to change the postion of gridview column in the gridview's `OnRowCreated` event.

I use this code

```
  TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[1];
  TableCell cell1 = e.Row.Cells[0];
  e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(1);
  e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
  e.Row.Cells.Add(cell1);
  e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
```

It works fine it moves column 0 and 1 to last positions of grid view

Now I want to move 3rd column of gridview to the first position, so I use

```
TableCell cell2 = e.Row.Cells[3];
e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(3);
e.Row.Cells.AddAt(0, cell2);
```

but it's not working....

Comment: How are you databinding the gridview? And to what?

Comment: I bind grid view on buttonclick using stored procedure

Comment: With what datastructure, datatable?

Comment: Cant't you alter the order of the columns on the datatable before binding it to the gridview?

Comment: ya sure.. i try it... dt.Columns["BookCode"].SetOrdinal(0); it works thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding the `GridView` to a `DataTable`, you could move the columns on the `DataTable` before you bind it to the `GridView`:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("x");
table.Columns.Add("y");
table.Columns.Add("z");

table.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");
table.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");
table.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");

//Move the column 
table.Columns["z"].SetOrdinal(0);

string value = table.Rows[0][0].ToString();
//Outputs 3

gridView.DataSource = table;
gridView.DataBind();
```